# Why do Observable.publish(Func1) and Observable.replay(Func1) return Observable?

Tags: rx-java

`Observable.publish()` and `Observable.replay()` returns ConnectableObservable.
But, when these method took interface as a parameter (such as `Observable.publish(Func1)` and `Observable.replay(Func1)` ), they would return Observable.

Why do they return Observable instead of ConnecatbleObservable?

If I used those methods with a parameter, I would get Observable. 
And then I called `submit(Observer)` to the observable, the observable would start working.
I could not call `connect()` since the observable would be Observable, not Connectable Observable.

If I have to use `Observable.publish(Func1)` and `Observable.replay(Func1)` to ConnectableObservable, I think that those methods must be in ConnectableObservable, not in Observable.

Why are they Observable's methods but not ConnectableObservable's methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those operators share the source for the duration of the function call, that is, you can subscribe to the Observable provided to your function and apply operators as you see fit. Those won't trigger multiple subscriptions to the original source; but it happens for each Subscriber to the result of the operator individually. Therefore, the subscription itself triggers the connection to the upstream and there is no need for doing it manually through a `ConnectableObservable`.

For example:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Subscribed!"))
.publish(o -> Observable.zip(o, o.skip(1), (a, b) -> a + b))
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

vs.

```
Observable<Integer> o = Observable.range(1, 10)
.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Subscribed!"));

Observable.zip(o, o.skip(1), (a, b) -> a + b)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the reason and the benefit. But I am totally confused with the JavaDocs explanation. Does this method do something with ConnectableObservable? But this is different from the topic of the question. I may think about this for a while and I may post the question when I could not reach the answer. By the way, I am glad that you became the lead contributor. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that those methods made the original ConnectableObservable to emit original values, but those methods made the returned Observable to emit the converted values.
And, if users wanted that only the particular Observer get the converted value, it make sense.

But, I still wonder why those methods are not in ConnectableObservable.